# I cannot access variables from my form in php

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have been looking at this for a while now, and looking at all similar questions but I can't find anything that solves my problem.

So I'm working in main't html and php building a pretend shopping site on my own server. This is just for my own educational purposes, so basically it's just for fun.

This is only the third time I've done anything with html or php, so there is a lot I still don't understand and this project might have gotten a little bigger than I intended.

I have a page where the 'user' signs in from, and from there I used the session to bring the data they put in (username and such) to make a very simple greeting. That has worked mostly. The only problem there is if I refresh the new page too much sometimes it disappears.

Main problem is in the new page. I have a form for items in the store, where the user can choose an amount they want to buy. However when the submit button is pressed my check shows that the form is empty, and I don't understand why. I've messed with it a bunch, started from using $_POST to $_GET but that didn't help. 
This is the start of my php which checks for things from the previous page.

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();

//check is post variables exist, if it does assign it
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $name = $_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['usersname'] = $name;
}
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $_SESSION['useremail'] = $email;
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $_SESSION['userpassword'] = $password;
}
$username = $_SESSION['usersname'];
$useremail = $_SESSION['useremail'];
$userpassword = $_SESSION['userpassword'];
```

Then the item list looks something like this.

```
 <!--- List of all items and how many they want --->
 <nav class="col-1">
 <p> Shopping List </p>
 <br/>
 <form action="index.php" method="GET" name="items">
    <table class="table1">
      <tr><th>WEAPONS</th></tr>
      <tr><td class="td1">
          <br/>
          <img class="disc" src="images/wand.png"></img><br/>
            Item Name: Butterfly Wand<br/>
            Price: $50.00<br/>
          <input type="number" name="wandNum" min="0" style="width: 50px"/>
          <br/>
          <?php $wandprice = 50.00; ?>
          </td></tr>
          <tr><td class="td1">
          <br/>
          <img class="disc" src="images/sword.png"></img><br/>
            Item Name: Normal Sword<br/>
            Price: $20.00<br/>
          <input type="number" name="swordNum" min="0" style="width: 50px"/>
          <br/>
          <?php $swordprice = 20.00; ?>
       </td></tr>
       <tr><td class="td1">
          <br/>
          <img class="disc" src="images/Bow_and_Arrows.png"></img><br/>
            Item Name: Normal Bow<br/>
            Price: $12.00<br/>
          <input type="number" name="bowNum" min="0" style="width: 50px"/>
          <br/>
       <?php $bowprice = 12.00; ?>
       </td></tr>
     </table> 
     <input type="submit" id="orderButton" name="order" value="Order"/>
    </form>      
  </nav>
```

Finally I wanted to put all the items and their information into an array somehow to store them. I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve it either. I haven't gotten to this part because the form above keeps coming up empty. Even if I type in a value for every item.

```
   if (isset($GET['items'])) {
        $wandnum = $_GET['wandNum'];
        $swordnum = $_GET['swordNum'];
        $bownum = $_GET['bowNum'];
```

This just checks to see if the value is over 0...I think..then hopefully it will put the values in the array.

```
          if ($wandnum > 0) {
             $wand = array ("Butterfly Wand", $wandprice, $wandnum);
             $items[] = array_push($wand);
           }
          if ($swordnum > 0) {
             $sword = array ("Normal Sword", $swordprice, $swordnum);
             $items[] = array_push($sword);
           }
           if ($bownum > 0) {
             $bow = array ("Normal Bow", $bowprice, $bownum);
             $items[] = array_push($bow);
           }
     }
    ?>
```

I can't get it past the if statement though because apparently it's not set. I don't have an IDE for html or php (any good free ones with debugging would be great) I ran the code through my command line and I ran fine. I just can't figure out why there are no values. My other page ran fine, so I'm not sure why this one is giving me trouble.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `$_GET['items']` instead of `$GET['items']`.  However, `isset($_GET['items'])` would always evaluate as false, since you don't have any form element with that name. You have added `name="items"` to the form itself, but the form tag won't be sent. Try and change it to `isset($_GET['order'])` (which is your button) instead.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. Must have happened when I was changing it from $_POST to GET. I used the form tag on other pages and it worked but I'll try that out also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at the beginning:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_GET['order'])) {
      if (isset($_GET['items'])) {
            $wandnum = $_GET['wandNum'];
            $swordnum = $_GET['swordNum'];
            $bownum = $_GET['bowNum'];

      if ($wandnum > 0) {
                 $wand = array ("Butterfly Wand", $wandprice, $wandnum);
                 $items[] = array_push($wand);
               }
              if ($swordnum > 0) {
                 $sword = array ("Normal Sword", $swordprice, $swordnum);
                 $items[] = array_push($sword);
               }
               if ($bownum > 0) {
                 $bow = array ("Normal Bow", $bowprice, $bownum);
                 $items[] = array_push($bow);
               }
         }

    }
```